# (xml) cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'init-param'

Tags: java, xml, spring

I do not know what caused this error.

Please help me fix this error.

[image]

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'init-param'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":module-name, "http://
 java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":description, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":display-name, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":icon, "http://
 java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":distributable, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":context-param, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":filter, "http://
 java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":filter-mapping, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":listener, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":servlet, "http://java.sun.com/
 xml/ns/javaee":servlet-mapping, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":session-config, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":mime-mapping, "http://
 java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":welcome-file-list, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":error-page, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":jsp-config, "http://
 java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":security-constraint, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":login-config, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":security-role, 
 "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":env-entry, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":ejb-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":ejb-local-ref, "http://
 java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":service-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":resource-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":resource-env-ref, "http://
 java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":message-destination-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":persistence-context-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/
 javaee":persistence-unit-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":post-construct, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":pre-destroy, "http://java.sun.com/
 xml/ns/javaee":data-source, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":message-destination, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":locale-encoding-mapping-list, 
 "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":absolute-ordering}' is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<init-param>` tag should be inside `<servlet>` tag like this:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name></servlet-name>
  <servlet-class></servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name></param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```